# How to use relative positioning for generating this graph

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am seeing various positioning and it is hard to avoid absolute positioning. Is there any better way to achieve the results with (mostly) relative positioning?

[image]

**==========update=============**

I need to add Charles etc. after Bob, and show the overlapping days (among all parties, i.e. from the max of all arrives to the min of all departures) automatically.

Comment: Yes, you can do that with only relative positions I think. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit? Do you need this with arbitrary arrive and leave values? Do you need more than two Alices and Bobs? Do you want the last bar to be actually automatic? Maybe a `\matrix` is helpful? Maybe it can be done with `pgfgantt` or `pgfplots` for a fully automatic solution.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel yes, i've updated the question with the info. please help out. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This *is* mostly relative positioning.

It uses the `node distance` to place
the nodes Alice, Bob, … and Overlapped days
but this value can also set by `bar distance`.
The bar height is determined by the value of `bar height`.
(Though, the bar will actually be twice that high.)

If the `bar height` is given without a unit it is basically a factor of the `bar distance`, when it is given with unit it's absolute.

The lower-left point and the upper right point of the rectangles are named `<nodename>-start` and `<nodename>-end` … these could have been used to also determine the max arrive and min leave point.

The legend node will be placed to the left of y = 0, so any values for the start of the rectangle should be to the right of that (and consider the label “… arrives”.

I hope I added some helpful comments in the code.
I've added a second example where some things go wrong (because this short example can't deal with everything).

---

Notes:

- When the whole range of *y* values should be available for the bars, either the legend nodes need to be placed after all bars are drawn or a `\matrix` should have been used.
- Instead of using `\barGraphStart` and `\barGraphEnd`, a similar tactic as the `fit` library provides could have been used to find the needed *x* values for the last bar.
- This is probably also doable in `pgfplots` and possible `pgfgantt`.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,backgrounds}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\tikzset{
  % allows "bar graph={…}" and … would be executed in /tikz/bar graph
  bar graph/.code=\pgfqkeys{/tikz/bar graph}{#1},
  % initializing the scope or picture as a bar graph diagram
  bar graph diagram/.style={
    start chain=legend going {below=of \tikzchainprevious.south east, anchor=north east},
    every path/.append style={bar graph={color=black}},
    /utils/exec=%
      \gdef\barGraphStart{-1000}\gdef\barGraphEnd{1000},% fake mind and max values
      % we define these macros here, so that they aren't available outside an actual bar graph
      \newcommand*\newBar[2][]{\tikzset{bar graph={new bar={text={##2},name={##2},@short={##2},##1}}}}
      \newcommand*\newCommon[1][]{%
        % the Overlapping days bar is just a normal bar … but
        % 1. the coordinates "\tikzlastnode-start" and "\tikzlastnode-end"
        %    get a special name so that we can use it again without knowing its name that the user might have changed
        % 2. label/.style=coordinate makes it that "… arrives" and "… leaves" won't show up
        % 3. and the bar goes from the calculated max to the calculates min.
        \newBar[##1,
          start coordinate/.style={alias={bargraph@start}},
          end coordinate/.style={alias={bargraph@end}},
          label/.style=coordinate,
          from={\barGraphStart} to \barGraphEnd
        ]{Overlapping days}
        % This just adds the two lines,
        % the coordinates @ and @@ just mark the start and the of the first line without
        % so that we can reference them in the second line
        \draw[bar graph/vert line] ([bar graph/bar down=2]bargraph@start) coordinate (@) --
          ([bar graph/bar up=3]0,0-|bargraph@start) coordinate (@@) node[bar graph/vert start node]
                                   (@-|bargraph@end) -- (@@-|bargraph@end) node[bar graph/vert end node];}
  },
  bar graph={
    % default values
    bar distance/.style={/tikz/node distance={#1}}, bar height/.initial=.4,
    name/.initial=bargraph@nonamegiven, text/.initial=, start/.initial=, end/.initial=,
    @short/.style 2 args={short={#1}}, short/.initial=,
    % default styles
     % this "text width" makes sure that the nodes have all the same width *and* are left of x = 0.
    legend node/.style={anchor=east,text width=width("Overlapping days")},
    label/.style={node font=\footnotesize},
      label start/.style={bar graph/label, anchor=north east},
      label end/.style={bar graph/label, anchor=north west},
    % the following styles can be used to change the label of the vertical lines
    vert start node/.style={below, at start, node contents={$\displaystyle\max_i t_{i,\text{arrive}}$}},
    vert end node/.style  ={below, at start, node contents={$\displaystyle\min_i t_{i,\text{leave}}$}},
    % this is the style for the vertical line
    vert line/.style={densely dashed, draw=black},
    % this style sets the TikZ colors
    color/.style={/tikz/fill={#1!40}, /tikz/draw={#1!75}},
    %
    from/.style args={#1 to #2}{start={#1},end={#2}}, % shortcut for setting start and end
    % bar down and bar up are used to shift coordinates up or down according to the bar height
    bar down/.style={shift=(down:#1*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/bar graph/bar height})}, bar down/.default=1,
    bar up/.style  ={shift=(up:  #1*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/bar graph/bar height})}, bar up/.default=1,
    % evaluates start and end so that max and min are calculated
    % and then draws rectangle from #1 to #2 in the xy coordinate system
    bar from/.style args={#1 to #2}{
      /utils/exec=%
        \pgfmathmax{#1}{\barGraphStart}\global\let\barGraphStart\pgfmathresult
        \pgfmathmin{#2}{\barGraphEnd}\global\let\barGraphEnd\pgfmathresult,
      % append after command allows \tikzlastnode to be referenced without having to know
      % the actual names but it needs to be protected so that it doesn't get overwritten
      % by other nodes/coordinates
      append after command={
                   ([bar graph/bar down] \tikzlastnode-|#1,0) {coordinate[bar graph/start coordinate/.try] (\tikzlastnode-start)}
         rectangle ([bar graph/bar up]   \tikzlastnode-|#2,0) {coordinate[bar graph/end coordinate/.try] (\tikzlastnode-end)
                                                  node[bar graph/label end  ] {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/bar graph/short} leaves }}
         (\tikzlastnode-start|-\tikzlastnode-end) node[bar graph/label start] {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/bar graph/short} arrives}}},
    % new bar is a specialized \path
    % 1. parameters are set
    % 2. legend node is placed with "bar from" style
    % 3. which then draws the rectangle at the same height of the node
    new bar/.code={%
      \path[bar graph={#1}] node (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/bar graph/name}) [
           on chain=legend, bar graph/legend node, bar graph/bar from=
             \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/bar graph/start} to \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/bar graph/end},
         ] {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/bar graph/text}};},
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[bar graph diagram]
\newBar[color=red,   from=1   to 5]{Alice}
\newBar[color=blue,  from=2   to 8]{Bob}
\newBar[color=yellow,from=1.5 to 6]{Charles}
\newCommon
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[bar graph diagram]
\newBar[from = -1 to 3] {America}
\newBar[from =  7 to 9] {Africa}
\newCommon
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help! How can I align text `Alice` and `Bob` and `Overlapped days` as left aligned?

Comment: @QiangLi This should do it: `start chain=legend going {below=of \tikzchainprevious.south west, anchor=north west}, every on chain/.style={anchor=west, text depth=+0pt, align=left, text width=width("Overlapped days")},` The text width makes sure that all nodes have the same width and their right border is still at `0`.

Comment: Your solution works great, but it is overly complex/advanced for me. Could you please explain a bit more, such as what `@` and `@@` means, how does the chain works, what does \pgfkeysvalueof have to do here, etc.? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @QiangLi I will, tomorrow. `@` and `@@` are just throwaway coordinates I define and use in the next line as reference. `\pkgfkeysvalueof` accesses the value of a value key. (This will be more helpful when you need to use this more than once in a document.)